# Tape deck solenoids

Tags: solenoid, vintage

I found an old tape deck recorder that I tore apart to scavenge for interesting parts.

Two different kinds of solenoids left me wondering:

[image]

[image]

From an old service manual (not related to the tape deck recorder I dismantled) I found three different kinds of solenoids:

1. Fast solenoid
2. Pinch roller solenoid
3. Head base solenoid

What are the above pictured solenoids?

Secondly, I've tried supplying a range of voltages to no avail; I can't make them move. Any suggestions on how to drive these solenoids?

Comment: First ring it out to make sure you are on the proper 2 terminals.
12v should make em go. Post back what the resistance is that will give a clue as to the voltage.

Comment: First one is 21 Ohms, second one is 30 Ohms.

Answer (score 0):

The RXP-042-0 solenoid appears to be very small. If it is about 1" long or smaller it will have a force of only a very few ounces. It is usually meant only to hold something in its energized position.
The solenoid in the assembly looks like it is actuating a pivot arm, perhaps to actuate or release one of the gears. You may have to remove it from the assembly to see if it is operational. It looks like it has two coils (??). It could be a magnetic latching type. If so, one voltage polarity will energize and latch it; the opposite polarity will release it.